# Open-source tools for run-off depth calculation

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, hydrology, precipitation

I am working on modeling surface run-off (in ArcGIS 10.2) due to a rain event (e.g., 5 year rain for a duration of 30 mins.) over an approx. area of 30 km2 for which I have a DEM and necessary soil as well as land-cover data (Manning's n values).

I want to build my own model, but in the meantime want to ask if any open-source tool calculates run-off depth at defined time intervals? The final result would be to generate run-off depths at certain time intervals and generate a movie out of it. Would be great if you could share your experiences with the available open-source hydrological models.

Comment: You might want to look into [Whitebox GAT](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml). It's a cool spatial analysis toolkit and it's open source. Here's [an answer on this site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109292/generate-channel-network-rainwater-run-off-which-algorithm-is-the-best) where the lead developer discusses applying Whitebox to a hydrology problem. You might also find the [Whitebox blog](https://whiteboxgeospatial.wordpress.com/) to be interesting.